# iPython: Using Pandas to count words, how do I count the least occuring?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, ipython, anaconda

Using iPython3.  I was able to figure out how to count the most occurring words in a column

```
import pandas as pd
dft = pd.read_csv('NYC.txt')
dft_counts = complaints['Provider'].value_counts()
dft_counts[:10]
```

How can  I code this to count the least occurring word?

Comment: You count and then reverse the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
counts = complaints['Provider'].value_counts()
counts[counts == 1]
```

show "counts" less or equal than 3:

```
counts[counts <= 3]
```

**OLD answer:**

you can do it this way:

```
complaints['Provider'].value_counts().nsmallest(1)
```

alternatively you can use `iloc` locator, which might be bit faster:

```
complaints['Provider'].value_counts().iloc[-1]
```

Comment: anyway to limit it to the smallest values that occur? I only want the words that occur once.

Comment: @JetCorey, i've updated my answer - please check. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html) with `-1` what return last value, because last value is smallest - [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) sorts `Serie`:

```
dft_counts.iat[-1]
```

If need all smallest values use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
dft_counts = (s.value_counts())
print (dft_counts)
6       3
5       3
null    2
18      1
3       1
22      1
0       1
dtype: int64

print (dft_counts.iat[-1])
1

print (dft_counts[dft_counts == dft_counts.iat[-1]])
18    1
3     1
22    1
0     1
dtype: int64
```

---

Alternatively use parameter `ascending=True` in `value_counts`:

```
dft_counts = (s.value_counts(ascending=True))
print (dft_counts)
0       1
22      1
3       1
18      1
null    2
5       3
6       3
dtype: int64

print (dft_counts[:3])
0     1
22    1
3     1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: anyway to limit it to the smallest values that occur? I only want the words that occur once.

Comment: Then you can use `(dft_counts[dft_counts == 1])`

Answer (score 0):

Just sort the Series:

```
dft_counts = complaints['Provider'].value_counts()
dft_counts.sort_values(["Provider"], ascending=[True])
```